# Session time out from sub web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a legacy asp.net web form web site, it uses forms authentication. Now, I have the requirement to create a new sub MVC application in the web site. My new application is most likely a SPA that means most actions are done through Ajax. Everything works fine until session time out, because once time out, my background Ajax returns the content of form login page instead of my json data. This is correct session behavior, but how can I know session time out in ajax and then redirect the page to login page?

Answer (score 2):

You can trap the failure of your AJAX calls and look for 401 result, which means that the request was not authorised.

I'm assuming you're using Web API for your service calls here - if you're calling methods on your normal MVC controller you'll need to do a little bit of work to ensure unauthenticated requests return 401 instead of redirecting you to the login page.

Comment: Yes, I am exactly using web API for my service, thanks for your answer.